# Where to store images correctly in VS 2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, embedded-resource

I am learning how to use VS 2008 for building projects. I would like to embedd images which my app is using internally. What is the correct way? I know I can create a folder in my project but not sure how to access the file stored there, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default win forms application adds a resource file to the solution. If you open it you can drag files onto it, and assign a name. Then access it in code like below

```
Properties.Resources.MyResourceName;
```

Default resource file:

[image: Resource file]

Answer (score 0):

Resource files would help, they can carry images.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you put the images in a folder or not is a matter of preference. I personally do it to avoid clutter in the project directory.

You can access the resources using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`

There is a write up here
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324567

Comment: That sounds quite complicated :( Is there not an easier way? Like place in the resources